# How to show only hidden files in Terminal?

Tags: command-line, ls

I have a directory that contains thousands of files, some of which are hidden.

The command `ls -a` lists all files, including hidden ones, but I need to just list hidden files.

What command should I use?

Comment: A simple `ls -ld .*` or `ls -ald .*` will work

Answer (score 301, accepted):

This command will list only hidden files:

```
ls -ld .?*
```

Explanation:

```
 -l     use a long listing format

 -d, --directory
              list  directory entries instead of contents, and do not derefer‐
              ence symbolic links

.?* will only state hidden files
```

Comment: You don't need the two question marks in there, the * covers it ( ? only matches any single character, * matches any number of them ).

Comment: @psusi, I think the intent is to exclude `.` and `..` from the match. However it will also exclude (perfectly legal) single-character hidden filenames such as `.a`, `.1` and so on. Perhaps a better extended glob would be `.!(|.)` i.e. literal dot followed by anything except nothing or another (single) dot i.e. `ls -d .!(|.)`

Comment: @steeldriver, neat, the ?? version does exclude "." and "..".  This seems to be the result of an interesting quirk: neither ? nor * will match a dot, but the ? must match *something* otherwise the name is ignored.

Comment: To identify directories and files add the F option, i.e., ls -ldF .?* directory names have "/" as last displayed character files don't.

Comment: This almost works except it also list hidden folder like .vim, which I consider not a file here. I modify it a bit  like

ls -ldp .?* | grep -v /

This only list hidden files not hidden folder

Comment: @steeldriver I understand that in `!(pattern-list)`, `pattern-list` is a list of one or more patterns separated by a `|`, but it is confusing for me that you don't have any pattern to the left of `|`. Could you please explain that syntax to me?

Comment: The proposed command will also list upward directories under .. The correct answer is `ls -ld .??*` It will only list hidden files in the current directory.

Comment: i like to put `-h` with most file-listing `Linux` commands because maths is not my strongest area (bytes -> MBs / GBs)

Comment: Be careful when using `.?*` with `rm -fr`. I got a very nice error: rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '..'. I will be a great disaster if no error appears.

Comment: Just being curious: Why `.?*` and not just `.*`? When the former would be mandatory over the latter?

Answer (score 43):

```
ls -d .!(|.)
```

Does exactly what OP is looking for .

Comment: How does that work?

Comment: list directory anything with a . and do not list anything without one is what it pretty much translates into.

Comment: I understand that in `!(pattern-list)`, `pattern-list` is a list of one or more patterns separated by a `|`, but it is confusing for me that you don't have any pattern to the left of `|`. Could you please explain that syntax to me?

Comment: @CarlosMendoza that would become the empty pattern, so this is like `.` not followed by (nothing or `.`), excluding `.` itself and `..`.

Comment: Don't forget to set extglob before using this solution! It may not be enabled by default.  
`shopt -s extglob`

Answer (score 24):

If you just want the files in your current directory (no recursion), you could do

```
echo .[^.]*
```

That will print the names of all files whose name starts with a `.` and is followed by one or more non-dot characters. Note that this will fail for files whose name starts with consecutive dots, so for example `....foo` will not be shown.

You could also use `find`:

```
find -mindepth 1 -prune -name '.*'
```

The `-mindepth` ensures we don't match `.` and the `-prune` means that `find` won't descend into subdirectories.

Answer (score 23):

```
ls -ad .*
```

works for me in Bash.

Comment: Shows `.` and `..` in Bash

Comment: @PengheGeng is correct `ls -ad .*` shows `.` and `..` - but `ls -ad .?*` shows `..`

Answer (score 4):

Using `find` and `awk`,

```
find . -type f | awk -F"/" '$NF ~ /^\..*$/ {print $NF}'
```

**Explanation:**

`find . -type f` --> List all the files in the current directory along with it's path like,

```
./foo.html
./bar.html
./.foo1
```

`awk -F"/" '$NF ~ /^\..*$/ {print $NF}'`

`/` as field separator awk checks for the last field staring with a dot or not. If it starts with a dot, then it prints the last field of that corresponding  line.

Comment: You could just use `find -type f`. You don't need to explicitly set the search path or `-name "*"`.

Answer (score 4):

`find` is usually a better option for complicated searches than using name globbing.

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '.*'
```

or

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '.*' -o -name '*~'
```

`find .` searches current directory

`-mindepth 1` excludes . and .. from the list

`-maxdepth 1` limits the search to the current directory

`-name '.*'` find file names that start with a dot

`-o` or

`-name '*~'` find file names that end with a tilde (usually, these are backup files from text editing programs)

However, this and all of the other answers miss files that are in the current directory's `.hidden` file. If you are writing a script, then these lines will read the `.hidden` file and display the file names of those that exist.

```
if [[ -f .hidden]] # if '.hidden' exists and is a file
then
    while read filename # read file name from line
    do
        if [[ -e "$filename" ]] # if the read file name exists
        then
            echo "$filename" # print it
        fi
    done < .hidden # read from .hidden file
fi
```

Comment: What's the `.hidden` file? Why would there ever be a file called `.hidden` that contains the file names? Anyway, if there is one why would you do something that complex when all you would need would be `cat .hidden`? Your `find` command is correct(ish) but the `-name '*~'` is irrelevant. Files that end in tildes are backup files but not hidden in any way.

Comment: @terdon The `.hidden` file is for files and folders you want to hide when you can't change the file/folder name to start with a dot. As for files that end in tildes, it depends on the system. `ls -B` will ignore such files, as will most GUI file explorers.

Comment: `cat .hidden` may show files that no longer exist if those files were deleted or moved since being added to the `.hidden` file.

Comment: This works well.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can do it with following command.

```
ls -a | grep "^\." | grep -v "^\.$" | grep -v "^\..$"
```

`ls -a` command you entered, that shows all files and directories in current working directory.

`grep "^\."` command I appended, that filters output to shows only hidden files(It's name starts with `"."`).

`grep -v "^\.$" | grep -v "^\..$"` command I appended, that filters output to exclude ., ..(They are current and parent directory).

If some filenames can have more than a line with `"\n"`, above example could be incorrect.

So I suggest following command to solve it issue.

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name ".[!.]*"
```

Comment: You should [never parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I saw your comment, It's so good. I edited my answer again. Thank you to your comment.

Answer (score 2):

What else you could have done, `is ls .?*` Or `ls .!(|)` that will show you everything in the current dir hidden files/dirs on the top and other files/dirs below

e.g: from my terminal

```
$ ls .?*       
.bash_history    .dmrc        .macromedia   .weather
.bash_logout     .gksu.lock   .profile      .wgetrc
.bash_profile    .bashrc.save .ICEauthority .toprc           .Xauthority
.bashrc          .lastdir     .viminfo      .xsession-errors
.bashrc~         .dircolors   .lynxrc       .vimrc           .xsession-errors.old

..:
Baron

.adobe:
Flash_Player

.aptitude:
cache  config

.cache:
compizconfig-1                              rhythmbox
dconf                                       shotwell
```

Now notice in the above results, it shows you every file/dir with its subdir and any hidden files right below.

```
[1:0:248][ebaron@37signals:pts/4][~/Desktop]
$ ls .!(|)
.bash_aliases  .bashrc1  .bashrc1~

..:
askapache-bash-profile.txt  examples.desktop             Public           top-1m.csv
backups             Firefox_wallpaper.png        PycharmProjects          top-1m.csv.zip
Desktop             java_error_in_PYCHARM_17581.log  Shotwell Import Log.txt  topsites.txt
Documents           Music                Templates            Videos
Downloads           Pictures                 texput.log           vmware
```

Sorry, I cannot comment. to explain the difference here between `ls .?*` and @cioby23 answer `ls -d .[!.]* .??*` And why it is actually printing hidden files twice is because literally you're asking twice `.??*`, `.?*`, `.[!.]*` they're the same thing, so adding any of them with different command characters will print twice.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach 1: `ls -d .{[!.],.?}*`**

Explain: I want to exclude `.` and `..` but include file such as `..i_am_also_a_hidden_file.txt`

1. `ls -d .*` undesirably shows `.` and `..`
2. `ls -d .?*` (the current accepted answer) undesirably shows `..`
3. `ls -d .[!.]*` undesirably will not show `..i_am_also_a_hidden_file.txt`
4. `ls -d .{[!.],.?}*` is the answer

**Approach 2: `ls -A | grep "\\."`**

I personally like this way better

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
ls -d .[!.]* .??*
```

This will allow you to display normal hidden files and hidden files which begin with 2 or 3 dots for example :   `..hidden_file`

Comment: With this I get all hidden files twice.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the command

```
ls -Ad .??*
```

This has the advantage of allowing multi-column listing, unlike the grep-based approach in the `ls -a | grep "^\."` solutions

Answer (score 1):

All the answers so far are based on the fact that files (or directories) which names start with a dot are "hidden". I came up with another solution, that might not be as efficient, but this solution does not assume anything about the names of the hidden files, and therefore avoids listing `..` in the result (as does the currently accepted answer).

The full command is:

```
ls -d $(echo -e "$(\ls)\n$(\ls -A)" | sort | uniq -u)
```

**Explanation**

What this does is list all the files (and directories) twice,

```
echo -e "$(\ls)\n$(\ls -A)"
```

but only showing hidden files once `-A`.

Then the list is sorted `| sort` which makes regular (unhidden) files appear twice and next to each other.

Then, remove all lines that appear more than once `| uniq -u`, only leaving unique lines.

Finally use `ls` again to list all the files with the user's custom options and without listing the contents of the directories in the list `-d`.

**EDIT (Limitations):**

As muru pointed out, this solution will not work correctly if there are files with names such as `escaped\ncharacter.txt` because `echo -e` will split the filename into two lines. It will also not work as expected if there are two hidden files with almost the same name except for a special character, such as `.foo[tab].txt` and `.foo[new-line].txt` as both of those are printed as `.foo?.txt` and would be eliminated by `uniq -u`

Comment: I think that's pretty much the definition of hidden files. Even the origin of these hidden files is from a bug in dealing with `.` as the first character.

Comment: I mention that (as fact) in the first paragraph. It still however gets a different result than the current accepted answer

Comment: Sure, it excludes `..`, but I wonder how well it works with filenames containing special characters.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by special characters, but I would think it would not pose a problem, as this solution does not assume anything about the filenames

Comment: Actually, you do assume at least one thing: filenames don't have newlines in them. Also: filenames don't have escape sequences in them that `echo -e` will interpret. Also: `ls` won't mangle filenames so that two different filenames get displayed the same (for example, in some versions `ls` will use `?` for special characters, so `.foo\tbar` (`\t` => tab) and `.foo\nbar` (`\n` => newline) will both show up as `foo?bar`).

Comment: You are right. I have edited this limitations into the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With bash, setting the `GLOBIGNORE` special variable is some non-empty value is enough to make it ignore `.` and `..` when expanding globs. From [the Bash docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion):

> The `GLOBIGNORE` shell variable may be used to restrict the set of
>   filenames matching a pattern. If `GLOBIGNORE` is set, each matching
>   filename that also matches one of the patterns in `GLOBIGNORE` is
>   removed from the list of matches. If the `nocaseglob` option is set,
>   the matching against the patterns in `GLOBIGNORE` is performed without
>   regard to case. The filenames `.` and `..` are always ignored when
>   `GLOBIGNORE` is set and not null. However, setting `GLOBIGNORE` to a
>   non-null value has the effect of enabling the dotglob shell option, so
>   all other filenames beginning with a `‘.`’ will match.

If we set it to `.:..`, both `.` and `..` will be ignored. Since setting it to anything non-null will also get this behaviour, we might as well set it to just `.`

So:

```
GLOBIGNORE=.
ls -d .*
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can also use `echo .*`

e.g.

```
user@linux:~$ echo .*
. .. .bash_aliases .bash_history .bash_logout .bashrc
user@linux:~$
```

If you prefer it in long list format, just convert the white space to a new line.

```
user@linux:~$ echo .* | tr ' ' '\n'
.
..
.bash_aliases
.bash_history
.bash_logout
.bashrc
user@linux:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

To list all hidden files and folders:

```
ls -ld .*
```

To list hidden files only:

```
ls -ld .*|grep -v ^d
```

To list hidden folders only:

```
ls -ld .*|grep ^d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use process substitution

```
 diff <(ls -1A) <(ls -1)
```

**Explanation:**

*Piping the stdout of a command into the stdin of another is a powerful technique. But, what if you need to pipe the stdout of multiple commands? This is where process substitution comes in.
Process substitution feeds the output of a process (or processes) into the stdin of another process*

[Cited from here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

So you are piping two outputs into the diff command.

The first command is "ls -1A". The "-A" flag works like the "-a" flag, but it does not show you "." and "..". So it basically shows you all the files and directories (both hidden and not-hidden) in a directory. The "-1" flag displays the output of "ls" one below the other vertically and not in a horizontal list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like `-d` because it only shows `no matches found` if there are no matches.

It also does not show `total [size]`  at top of lines.

I think `ls -lA --ignore "[^\.]*"` is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

`ls -A | grep "^\."`

- `ls -A`   lists all files (hidden and non-hidden)
- `grep "^\."` filter apart the ones starting with a dot

Comment: ls -a will also list all the files: hidden and non-hidden

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the tips on here!

Here's a function for your .bash_aliases file that handles no command arguments, doesn't throw errors on directories without hidden files, appends / on listed directories, and outputs to a single column.

```
lsa () {

    # Exit codes with/without argument are 0 if no hidden files present
    EXIT=$(ls -1d .!(|.) |& grep -q "No such file"; echo $?)
    EXIT_ARG=$(cd $1; ls -1d .!(|.) |& grep -q "No such file"; echo $?)

    # If no argument
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        if [ $EXIT -eq 0 ]; then
            printf ""
        else
            ls -1dp .!(|.)
        fi
    
    # If argument
    else
        if [ $EXIT_ARG -eq 0 ]; then
            printf ""
        else
            (cd $1; ls -1dp .!(|.))
        fi
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A long list of answers, let's add one more, which doesn't seem to be included:

`$ ls -lA | grep ' \.'`

The -A option to ls includes all hidden files, except `.` and `..`.
grep, as used above finds  `.` (space, dot) and filters away lines that do not have that.

`$ ls -lA | grep -E '^d.* \.` 
... lists only dirs.

`$ ls -lA | grep -Ev '^d.*' | grep ' \.'`
... lists only files.

*... and that last can be used as alternative for files-only*
`$ ls -lA | grep -E '^d.*' | grep ' \.'`
*just remove the -v flag on grep*

Answer (score 0):

The code below only shows hidden files:

```
ls -A | grep "^\."
```

or

```
ls -ap | grep -v / | grep "^\."
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps from their official github: https://gist.github.com/barnes7td/3804534

Setup Terminal for Sublime Shorcut `subl`: Open terminal and type:

1. Create a directory at `~/bin`:

   ```
   mkdir ~/bin
   ```
2. Copy sublime executable to your `~/bin` directory:

   ```
   ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
   ```

##### BASH (Mac OS default)

Use these instructions unless you know you have zsh

3. If using bash (Mac OS default) add line to `~/.bash_profile` file:

   ```
   echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin' >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```
4. Set sublime as your default editor

   ```
   echo "export EDITOR='subl -w'" >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```

##### ZSH

If you don't know what zsh is you don't have it.

3. If using zsh add line to `~/.zshrc` file:

   ```
   echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin' >> ~/.zshrc
   ```
4. Set sublime as your default editor

   ```
   echo "export EDITOR='subl -w'" >> ~/.zshrc
   ```
5. Restart terminal and type:

   ```
   subl .
   ```

   Sublime should open up in the current directory.
6. Check unix commands:

   ```
   ls
   ```

   You should get a directory listing.

##### Windows

Put the `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2` in your PATH.

Create a `subl.bat` file and save it in the directory: `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2`

Inside the file put:

```
start sublime_text.exe %*
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the command

```
ls -pa | grep -v /
```

Explanation of flags:

- `-p` will append "/" indicator to directories
- `-a` will list hidden files
- `grep -v /` commands will return the lines that do not contain a slash.

Answer (score -1):

You could also install the much friendlier Rust version of `ls`: [`exa`](https://github.com/ogham/exa). Then use the following to get a much nicer tree visualization of all the files:

```sh
exa -Ta
```

If you really end up liking `exa` like me, you can override `ls` with an alias on your `.bashrc`: `alias ls="exa"`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use grep:

```
ls -a | grep '^\.'
```

Comment: This answer doesn't only show hidden files as the question requested; it shows hidden directories too.