# How can I exclude . and .. when listing hidden items?

Tags: command-line, ls, hidden-files

`ls -d .*` lists only hidden "items" (files & directories). (I think) technically it lists every item beginning with `.`, which includes the current `.` and above `..` directories.

I also know that `ls -A` lists "almost all" of the items, listing both hidden and un-hidden items, but excluding `.` and `..`. However, combining these as `ls -dA .*` doesn't list "almost all" of my hidden items.

How can I exclude . and .. when listing hidden items?

Comment: maybe `ls -d +(.)+([^.])` (you need extglob set)

Comment: This works... how?

Comment: +(.)  match one or more dot follow by +([^.]) one or more non dots, it will match ... and so on ... you could optimize some more

Comment: @jonnybolton16 that is a regex https://regex101.com/ very handy ;)

Comment: [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)

Comment: @bac0n Consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: @bac0n yeah, post it :)

Comment: Hold up; this hasn't worked gloally... it worked on my local machine, but after SSHing into my work machine, it doesn't work. Maybe that machine doesn't have extglob. I don't know what that is, and I doubt I'd have the rights to set it.

Comment: shopt -s extglob, its perfectly safe to add to your .bashrc

Comment: after doing that I get ```ls: cannot access +(.)+([^.]): No such file or directory```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the second answer in:

- [How to show only hidden files in Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468901/how-to-show-only-hidden-files-in-terminal)

This works on my machine (I'm not using SSH like the OP though):

```
ls -d .!(|.)
```

If there are no hidden files or directories you will get an error message:

```
$ ls -d .!(|.)
ls: cannot access '.!(|.)': No such file or directory
```

The error message occurs on directories with no hidden files because `.` and `..` are excluded.

### `shopt` consideration

From comments:

`ls -d .[!.]*` works without `extglob`

Comment: Great! This works on my own machine and my work machine. But strangely it doesn't work on the gateway machine - I get the message ```-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('```. It's not a big deal, but it would be nice for it to work there too

Comment: @jonnybolton16 I wonder what `bash --version` returns on each of the three machines? Perhaps that might be a clue. Other than that run `diff` command on results of `shopt` output from different machines my give the reason.

Comment: ```4.2.46(2)``` for work machine, ```4.4.20(1)``` for local machine and ```4.1.2(1)``` for gateway. From `shopt` I can see that the gateway has `extglob off`. This could be the issue. Doing `shopt -s extglob` made it work; though I could have sworn I did that earlier

Comment: `ls -d .[!.]*` works without `extglob`

Comment: I updated the answer from my phone to briefly reflect your new discoveries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any set of options, and search the output stream for a matching string or not a matching string using `grep`.

From grep man page:

```
   grep  searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are
   named, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name) for lines
   containing  a  match to the given PATTERN.  By default, grep prints the
   matching lines.
```

So for example if my `ls -A` output is:

```
   . .. Desktop Documents Downloads
```

My `ls -A |grep "Do"` would be:

```
Documents
Downloads
```

I can also use invert search using `-v` to search for anything **that is not** my expressions.

From grep man page:

```
-v, --invert-match select non-matching lines
```

So in your case the expression would be: `ls -d .* |grep "[.][a-z]\|[0-9]"`

Comment: No, this doesn't work... it returns empty

Comment: sorry, I had an extra " at the end of my command - updated the line

Comment: I didn't include the extra " (I didn't even see it lol). The command ```ls -d | grep -v "[.]\|[..]"``` doesn't work

Comment: You are correct, you can just use this, without -v: `ls -d .* |grep "[.][a-z]"`

Comment: Overall the best practice is to find something that is shortest to write and manipulate, but also that works. I tried that in my terminal this time and it works. Will edit my answer in accordance.

Comment: I would ammend to [aA0-zZ9] to capture capitals and numbers

Comment: Overall the expression is up to you. I just don't have an example of a the file list you have. If you are looking for the most general expression, then yes. You can also add numbers and characters. This method in the answer is very flexible if you would want to continue omitting other files as well.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sold on this method though. It's returning the results in a single column, rather than spanning the width of the terminal, and it doesn't use colours (my ```ls``` is aliased using ```--color=auto```)

Answer (score 0):

You can use also `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.*'
```

which prints out full path, or:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.*' -printf "%f\n"
```

This works also for empty directories / no such files.

Comment: this will not find directories.