# How to recursively list only hidden files from a terminal

Tags: command-line, ls

I would like to do something like

```
ls -RA .?* >> LSRA.list
```

but with this command and some other variants I tried, I always get also all non-hidden files in the directory where I am.

Namely, if the directory contains files

```
.hiddenfile foo
```

with above command I get ther recursive list of both, while I would like to ave only the recursive list of files and directory starting with . (but not the . directory itself!)

I checked answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468901/how-to-show-only-hidden-files-in-terminal/468902#468902) but I did't find the solution to my problem.

**Update:** best options found so far:

```
 ls -RA .!(|.)*
```

and

```
 find -path './.*' -name '.*' -empty -printf %P\\n
```

the latter recursively list all hidden files in all hidden directory (so if am hidden directory contains a non-hidden files, it does not show that file).

**Further update.** both answers of bac0n and vanadium work: I cannot accept both! (first one recursively shows nonhidden files in hidden directory, latter one recursively shows only hidden files)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To recursively list only hidden files from a terminal, you can use the tool `find` with the `-type f` option:

```
find ~ -type f -name '.*'
```

This will find all files in the user's home directory for which the basename starts with a dot, i.e., a hidden file or folder. Remove `-type f` to list both hidden files and folders, or specify `type d` to list only hidden directories. Specify any other directory by replacing `~` with a valid pathname. Specify `.` to list hidden files in the current working directory and below.

Comment: For me it does not, and it is not supposed to do so. "find" will match the glob for the *basename* only. It is straightforward use of `find`. Can you indicate which OS version you use? For me, the option `-A` for `ls` you mention does not work. Perhaps working under a different shell?

Comment: Difficult to see from here what exactly might be going on on your system.

Comment: Perhaps also try `'\.*`. This "escapes" the dot, and prevents it from being interpreted as a wildcard for one character. Not needed for me, but I added it to the question nevertheless.

Comment: Forget about my comment on the `-A` option: I forgot I have `exa` installed, an alternative `ls` command that does not support the option.

Comment: My mistake: the files that seemed "nonhidden" where just file with a long path and the "dot" was at the breakline! :( sorry. But now I created a test directory and seems to work... too much! that is to say, do not show nonhydden files in hidden directories

Comment: Please note your question was explicitly to "list only hidden files": see your title. In the body of your question, you indicate: " I would like to ave only the recursive list of files and directory starting with . (but not the . directory itself!)". That is what this answer does. Also, please update your question for the comment on my answer.

Comment: update the question and deleted erroneous comments. Sorry about that, and thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3):

It may be hard to match every corner-case:

```
find \( -path './.*' -type d -empty -printf %P/\\n \) -o -type f -path './.*' -printf %P\\n
```

Comment: That seems to work!

Comment: puh... will make some description ... later...

Comment: I accepted the other question because it is more coherent with the title of the question, so for other users it may be better like that. But I was in fact interested in your answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that handles no command arguments, doesn't throw errors on directories without hidden files, appends / on listed directories, and outputs to a single column.

```
lsa () {

    # Exit codes with/without argument are 0 if no hidden files present
    EXIT=$(ls -1d .!(|.) |& grep -q "No such file"; echo $?)
    EXIT_ARG=$(cd $1; ls -1d .!(|.) |& grep -q "No such file"; echo $?)

    # If no argument
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        if [ $EXIT -eq 0 ]; then
            printf ""
        else
            ls -1dp .!(|.)
        fi
    
    # If argument
    else
        if [ $EXIT_ARG -eq 0 ]; then
            printf ""
        else
            (cd $1; ls -1dp .!(|.))
        fi
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly run below commands to list only hidden items from any location(location can change on below commands) recursively and suppress error in order to show only expected result.

#to list every type of file/folder/data/objects... which are hidden in linux

```
sudo find / -iname '.*' 2> /dev/null|nl
```

#to list only hidden files recursively in linux

```
sudo find / -type f -iname '.*' 2> /dev/null|nl
```

#to list only hidden directories recursively in linux

```
sudo find / -type d -iname '.*' 2> /dev/null|nl
```