# Lists only hidden files in my home directory in long format?

Tags: command-line, ls

I don't want to list recursively the sub directory as well. I have tried following but it did not worked correctly.

```
ls -lad ~/.* 
ls -la ~/.*
```

Comment: version of ubuntu?

Comment: What do you mean when you say `but it did not worked correctly`. Please elaborate.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/468901/how-to-show-only-hidden-files-in-terminal#:~:text=https%3A//askubuntu.com/a/1234910/15811

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`$ ls -lA | grep ' \.'`

The -A option to ls includes all hidden files, except `.` and `..`.
grep, as used above finds  `.` (space, dot) and filters away lines that do not have that.

`$ ls -lA | grep -E '^d.* \.` 
... lists only dirs.

`$ ls -lA | grep -Ev '^d.*' | grep ' \.'`
... lists only files.

*... and that last can be used as alternative for files-only*
`$ ls -lA | grep -E '^d.*' | grep ' \.'`
*just remove the -v flag on grep*

Comment: This also includes directories.

Comment: yes ofcourse...

Comment: *... updated, possibly finished.*